# Cancel several axios requests with same CancelToken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have different react modules in a view, while each is calling an API via `axios`. When going to another view, all calls should be cancelled. However, when returning to this view, the calls should be started again (those are in `componentDidMount()`).

File `AxiosCancellation.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
let cancel;
export var cancelRequest = (message) => {
  if (cancel) cancel(message);
};
export var setCancelToken = (c) => {
  cancel = c;
};
export var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
```

File 2:

```
import {CancelToken, setCancelToken} from "AxiosCancellation";
export var get1: () => {
  return axios.get('/get1', {
    cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
      setCancelToken(c);
    })
  }).then(handleResponse);
}
```

File 3:

```
import {CancelToken, setCancelToken} from "AxiosCancellation";
export var get2: () => {
  return axios.get('/get2', {
    cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
      setCancelToken(c);
    })
  }).then(handleResponse);
}
```

When I now call `cancelRequest()` when clicking a link on the navbar, only one call is cancelled. How can I cancel multiple calls (that are in different files)?

Answer (score 0):

try using this lib [axios-tx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-tx)

Just make sure you are using thesame instance for all the related calls (that should be canceled together)